# Conditional showing in Angular + ionic: Show if Id has specific value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to show a block in Angular only if ID is of specific value.

I tried this in the following code `ng-if="{{what.nid}} === 12"`, but it didn't work.

### This is what I tried:-

```
 <ng-map zoom="11" center="[40.74, -74.18]" ng-if="{{what.nid}} === 12">
      <marker position="[40.74, -74.18]" />
      <shape name="circle" radius="400" center="[40.74,-74.18]" radius="4000" />
      <control name="overviewMap" opened="true" />
  </ng-map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-if` accepts an expression, so using `{{}}` inside of it is not necessary, just use `ng-if="what.nid === 12"`

Comment: This didn't work. I had to put 12 in quotes. Like this `ng-if="what.nid === '12' "`. Accepting this though.